# Factorisation of polynomials without polynomial division

Tags: polynomials

As an example I would like to factorize the following polynomial (I actually know the solution, but this is just an example):

$m^2-q^2+10q-25$

Polynomial division should **not** be used. Of course there is the trial and error method, but I wondered if for this more complicated polynomials (compared to the classical $a^2+2ab+b^2$) there is any other systematic approach?

Thanks

Comment: But why not use polynomial division?

Comment: It was actually the exercise of a school kid, and they have not learned polynomial division yet

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If you can write $q^2 - 10 q + 25$ as a square, then you can immediately realize the given expression as a difference of perfect squares, which can be factored as $$a^2 - b^2 = (a - b) (a + b).$$

Comment: Aha, so by starting once with m+.. and once with m- we basically remove all unwanted products of the multiplication with m (what I mean is when having (m-q+5)(m+q-5))

Comment: @TestGuest Yes, that's exactly right.